# How do I get String value out of NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, string, nsmutablearray, didselectrowatindexpath

Code:

```
[self.menuList addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       NSLocalizedString(@"PropertySubtype2fTitle", @""), 
                                       kTitleKey,
                                       publishNoOfRoomsViewController, 
                                       kViewControllerKey, nil]];
```

menuList is a NSMutableArray.

I want to read the PropertySubtype2fTitle localized string later in the code, like in:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To fetch an entry from a NSDictionary, you can use

```
[NSDictionary objectForKey:(id)keyValue]
```

. To fetch an entry from a NSArray / NSMutableArray, you can use

```
[NSArray objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index]
```

. In combination and applied to your example that should be:

```
NSString *title = [[menuList objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:kTitleKey];
```

whereas index would be an unsigned integer (NSUInteger).

Answer (score 0):

Why not directly use the `NSMutableDictionary`?

For example:

```
NSData *getData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
NSError *errorData;
NSMutableDictionary *dicData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                     JSONObjectWithData:getData
                                     options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                     error:&errorData];

if( errorData )
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [errorData localizedDescription]);
}
else {

    NSString *title =   [[dicData[@"items"] objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"titlekey"];
    NSLog(@"titlekey %@",title);
}
```